# Angular2 App with external reference to Auth0Lock fails with NotFound Error when run from Azure

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service, auth0

I have been building and app based on angular2-seed. I am now using the seed's production build that combines all the local js code into a single app.js file for deployment. It works fine on my local machine, but when I move it to an Azure website. Loading the page produces this error:

**> ReferenceError: Auth0Lock is not defined**

It is defined in this external link:

**<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.0/lock.js">/script>**

This was included in the <head> section of index.html, before the app.js file, which is included in the body.

My code that reference the component is simply

**this.lock = new Auth0Lock('pwC5..**.

Is there some setting on Azure that is preventing the load of the external file? Or is something else going on?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Do you include the `lock.js` cdn script before your custom `app.js` script? Please try to include the `lock.js` script inside the `<header>` tag in the html page. Otherwise, is it convenient of you to provide your application's repository?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yes this lock.js script is included before the app.js file which is included in the body. I've updated my question to include that fact.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'provide my application's repository'. Here is the URL if that is what you mean http://jovenesadelantetest.azurewebsites.net

Comment: I visited your application in Chrome, but I only can find the `app.js` and `shims.js` included in your frontend html page, I cannot find the `lock.js`. It may be the crime, could you please double check the `lock.js` is included successfully? Otherwise, you can try to download the script to your application, and include the script from relative path in your application directory.

Comment: I found the issue -- user error. I was so focused on making sure that the correct version of app.js was in place, that I missed the fact that index.html was an incorrect version.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAL had the answer: "This sort of thing has cropped up before, Dave, and it has always been due to human error."    Thanks to Gary Liu of MSFT for pointing me in the right direction. The version of index.html that I had on Azure wasn't the one I thought it was.